# Matlab, define submatrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, submatrix

I got a 10x10 matrix with a bunch of zeroes and an element of the value 1.
I'm trying to create a submatrix with the element of 1 and its surrounding.

Problem:

[image]

This is just an example, the element "1" is placed anywhere within the matrix. I do realise I can find my element using find `find(MATRIX==1)`.

How do I define my 3x3 submatrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'find' to get the indices of that '1' element, and construct the desired matrix from them. Something like:

```
[row, col] = find(MATRIX==1);
subMatrix = MATRIX(row-1:row+1, col-1:col+1);
```

Of course, you might need to check that the '1' element is not in a border of the MATRIX (i.e. row-1, row+1, col-1, col+1 are not out of bounds).

Best.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, appreciate it.